# Deleting a listbox item will it keep it's index number?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

so I have a listbox and I have filled it with the values of

```
hi - 0
hello - 1
abc - 2
dog - 3
cat - 4
bear - 5
```

(the # represents its index value) If I were to delete the entry cat - 4 will bear have the index value of 4 or will it still remain at index value 5?

Comment: If you already have it, you can try it and check the result..

Comment: ListBox indices represent the current index in the list. If you remove an item, all indices after the removed one, will change. In your example, if you remove all items except for `dog`, there will be only one item with index `0`.

Comment: Thanks, is there a clever way to hold the values of the index so I can use this value for something else? The only way I can think of is running a loop to store all the index values and then delete the items.

Comment: I suppose you could just add a null value to the list as a placeholder, such as a blank string that won't display, for example. Would that fit your needs?

Comment: Thanks, yeah setting the value to null seems to do trick!

Answer (score 0):

No, the above elements will not retain their old indexes - they will shuffle down. This is because they're stored as a linked list (`List<T>`) so any gap in the list would actually break the chain and any elements past the "gap" would be inaccessible.

Linked lists work by having each element store a reference to the memory location of the next (think pointers if you're acquainted with C++). So if one element is removed. The object has to "repair"  the list by re-linking the element after the removed one with the element before. As stated before, the elements beyond the removed element would be inaccessible if the link were not fixed (and fixing the link means that the elements shift down).

For example, suppose I had a `List<T>` of `string` with the following elements at the following index positions:

```
0 - "Bob" 
1 - "Joe"
2 - "Bill"
```

The way this works is that Bob would hold a reference to Joe, and Joe would have a reference to Bill. So when you access an index, a recursive algorithm is called, starting at 0 (Bob) and getting the reference to the next element. This process repeats twice for an index of two (get Bob's reference (Joe), then get the reference of that (Bill), which is your index two). It would not occur at all for an index of 0, because 0 is the starting element, so it would just return that.

That last bit wasn't really relevant to your question, but hopefully you learned something new :)

Comment: `List<T>` is not a "linked list". Describing it as such just confuses things.

Comment: Oh, my apologies - I thought it was a linked list structure! Thanks for clearing that up; what is it exactly do you know?

Comment: From [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx): _"It implements the IList<T> generic interface by using an array whose size is dynamically increased as required."_

Answer (score -2):

```
var listArray = yourListbox.items

foreach(var iem in listArray)
{
   Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());
}
```

Comment: I know that you're suggesting that OP should test his question, and you're right, but do you think you could explain that in your answer? Also - not to be too pedantic but I think `var iem` is intended to be `var item` ;)